# Can a person write a method to utilize Lambda expressions?

Tags: c#

I have never used Lambda expressions before and would like to be able to write my own methods that can use lambda expressions. Is there a way to do this and if so why is my method not working below.

**Question: Can my testString method take a lambda expression like my p.Zip example does?**

Code:

```
    public void testString(string a, string b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A: " + a + "B: " + b);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] p = { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
        string[] s = { "AA-A", "BB-B", "CC-C", "DD-D" };

        var statesWithCodes = p.Zip(s, (c, ss) => c + ": " + ss); //lambda expressions

        foreach (var v in statesWithCodes)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(v);
        }
```

--This is the code that i am not certain why is not working with lambda expressions or even

### if it is supposed to be able to work

```
        string temp1 = "a";
        string temp2 = "b";
        testString((temp1,temp2) => temp1 + " -- " + temp2);
```

New Code added so that I can see if I can call a delegate function from the answers below. Part of it works but what if I want to have several functions that meet the delagates parameters list.

Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace DDHTestDelegate
{
    class Program
    {
        // declare a delegate that takes in two strings and returns a string:
        delegate string StringDelegate(string inputString, string baseString);

        public void someFunction(string a, string b)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("String a: " + a);
            Console.WriteLine("String a: " + b);
        }

        // this calls the delegate function
        static string Test(StringDelegate theFunction, string inputString1, string inputString2)
        {
            return theFunction(inputString1, inputString2);
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Test((input1, input2) => input1 + ": " + input2, "S1", "S2"));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the part that I think is throwing me off right here and this is exactly what I want to do at this point.

```
   (input1, input2) => input1 + ": " + input2
```

How is this code being used in the Test function with the StringDelegate because that function only returns. This will compile and run but I am not exactly certain as to why it is working the way that it is.

More Code:

```
         Console.WriteLine(Test(someFunction("w","i")), 
                          "S1", 
                          "S2");
```

Why is this code not working either. The Test function takes three arguements. 1 a function, the other two strings. Why is this causing problems.

Other example:

```
    static public void testString(Func<string, string, string> function)
    {
       temp1 = "a";
       temp2 = "b";
       Console.WriteLine(function(a, b));
    }

    testString((temp1, temp2) => temp1 + " -- " + temp2);
```

The above example is not working completely either.

Error List:

```
Error   1   The name 'temp1' does not exist in the current context  C:\Users\itpr13266\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\DDHTestDelegate\Program.cs  27  12  DDHTestDelegate
Error   2   The name 'temp2' does not exist in the current context  C:\Users\itpr13266\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\DDHTestDelegate\Program.cs  28  12  DDHTestDelegate
Error   3   The name 'a' does not exist in the current context  C:\Users\itpr13266\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\DDHTestDelegate\Program.cs  29  39  DDHTestDelegate
Error   4   The name 'b' does not exist in the current context  C:\Users\itpr13266\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\DDHTestDelegate\Program.cs  29  42  DDHTestDelegate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't always as easy to write as what Marcin posted but you can explicitly declare a delegate like:

```
// declare a delegate that takes in two strings and returns a string:
delegate string StringDelegate(string inputString, string baseString);
```

You would then define your function that uses this delegate:

```
// this calls the delegate function
static string Test(StringDelegate theFunction, string inputString1, string inputString2)
{
    return theFunction(inputString1, inputString2);
}
```

Finally you can use this with a lambda like:

```
Console.WriteLine(Test((input1, input2) => input1 + ": " + input2, "S1", "S2"));
```

Again, maybe not exactly as simple to start with as the `Func` option, but it can be useful if you want to define your delegates separately from the functions that use these delegates.

Answer (score 4):

You can take a lambda (or delegate in general) as method parameter. The easiest way to do that is to use `Action<>` and `Func<>` types.

```
public void testString(Func<string, string, string> function)
{
    temp1 = "a";
    temp2 = "b";
    Console.WriteLine(function(a, b));
}
```

Now, you can call it like that:

```
testString((temp1,temp2) => temp1 + " -- " + temp2);
```

Comment: When I try this in my program for testing I get all kinds of errors in the code can you paste up a working model for an example.